# What does the $this->request->is('put')) method do in CakePHP?

Tags: php, function, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

This is my first time to CakePHP, I cannot understand what does `$this->request->is('put'))` means?

Can anyone please help me into this, I'm sorry for being a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

PUT is the POST HTTP Request version of "edit" action, when you send data that you want to change something (not insert) you send a PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

The PUT request is used to update the existing records. Do take note that the PUT request will replace the existing data of the record, if the values are set. The PUT request is normally used when building RESTful services.

```
$this->request->is('put'))
```

The is('put') condition can be used to check if the HTTP request made is a PUT.